# Facing issue with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, range

facing problem in setting the range in an if statement

```py
if n>=6 & n<=20:
    print("Weird")
```

When I check the output for `n=6` and `n=20` if a not getting weird as output. I included 6 and 20 in the statement, but it doesn't work

Comment: Try `and` instead of `&`.

Comment: I think you want `and`, not `&`.